# Remove an item from a Set that doesn't match criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

For a school project, the goal is to do a fuzzy match of a query string to a lyric string inside a Song object.  The overall data structure is a TreeMap of unique words paired with sets of songs that contain that word in the lyrics.

I have my preliminary match set of songs that contain the query string.  The twist here is that I have to assign each result song a rank based on the number of characters in the match section, spaces inclusive.  For example, searching for "she loves you" returns these among the matches:

"... She loves you ..."  The Beatles, rank= 13
"... She just loves you ..."  Bonnie Raitt, rank=18
"... She loves me, well you ..."  Elvis Presley, rank=23

The I'm using to sort the results is:

```
for (int i=0; i<lyrics.length; i++) {
  if (lyrics[i].equals(query[0])) { //got the start point
  start=i; //adjust the start index point

  //loop through lyrics from start point
  for (int j=1; j<query.length; j++) {
    if (lyrics[j].equals(query[query.length-1])) {
        end=i; //found the last word
    }

    //if next lyric word doesn't match this query word
    if (!lyrics[i+j].equals(query[j])) {

    //advance loop through lyrics. when a match is found, i is adjusted to
    //the match index
    for (int k= i+j+1; k<lyrics.length; k++) {
        if (lyrics[k].equals(query[j]) || lyrics[k].equals(query[0]))
            i=k++;
        } //end inner advance loop

    } //end query string test

  }//end query test loop

  song.setRanks(start, end); //start and end points for the rank algorithm.

} //end start point test
```

Since all the songs in the result set contain the query words in any particular order, they will not all be included in the result printout.  Using this algorithm, how can I set a trigger to remove the song from the set if the query is not matched to any particular length?

Edit- Is Lucene a solution to this?  This is a gray area in the project, and one I will bring up in class tomorrow.  He is allowing us to choose whatever data structures for this project, but I don't know if using another implementation for string matching will pass muster.

Edit 2 @ belisarius- I don't see how edit distance applies here.  The most common application of Levenshtein distance requres a String a of length n and String b of length m, and the distance is the number of edits required for a==b.  For this project, all that is required is the rank of characters in a match, with the start and end points unknown.  With some changes to the code posted above, I am finding the start and end points accurately.  What I need is a way to remove the non-matches from the set if the the lyrics don't fit the search in any fashion.

Comment: Take a look at the "Edit Distance" (google for it)

Comment: already did, but can't see how it fits with my dilemma

Comment: I have a workaround working: a Set.remove(Song) throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` since I'm iterating through the Set using the enhanced for loop, so I used a boolean trigger to switch to false if the end of the lyric string has been reached without a match to the last query word.  Based on that value, the Song will be added to the result queue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to have a look at the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein%5Fdistance). The Apache commons-lang library implemented it in version 2.1 in the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

A Patricia trie might just do it for you.

Go through this one see if it has what u need.

http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/